# Making sure dispatch and reducers work before react dom

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-dom

```
Api.GET({
    url: USER_LOGIN_AUTH,
    payload: null,
    onSuccess: response => {
        window.__MUI_USE_NEXT_TYPOGRAPHY_VARIANTS__ = true;
        store.dispatch(getUserAction(response.data));
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <App />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>,
            document.getElementById("root")
        );
    },
    onFailure: () => {
        ReactDOM.render(<Unauthorized />);
    }
});
```

How can I make sure that the `store.dispatch` and its respective reducers has set the new state before the line `ReactDOM.render` execues.

I want to hold my app from being rendered before the initial state has been set.

Thanks

Comment: Redux dispatch is synchronous. The store will be updated before the next line is evaluated. Do you have problems with the code you posted?

Comment: @estus I am using redux logger and sometimes it looks like the app loaded before the redux logger put logs in my console. Functionality wise it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using Promise can help :

```
Api.GET({
    url: USER_LOGIN_AUTH,
    payload: null,
onSuccess: response => {
    window.__MUI_USE_NEXT_TYPOGRAPHY_VARIANTS__ = true;

    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        try {
            resolve(store.dispatch(getUserAction(response.data)));
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }

    }).then(store => {

        ReactDOM.render( < Provider store = {store} >
            <BrowserRouter >
            <App />
            </BrowserRouter> </Provider>,
            document.getElementById("root")
        );

    })

},
onFailure: () => {
    ReactDOM.render( < Unauthorized / > );
}
});
```

Comment: How does it help? The question doesn't mention that `dispatch` returns a promise. If `dispatch` returns a promise because of some async middleware, it could be chained with `then`, while `new Promise` is constructor antipattern.